# Breadcrumb Navigation issue when navigating to Sitecontents

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, typescript, reactjs, breadcrumb

I have the Breadcrumb navigation installed in my sites which works fine when navigating to the Lists or Libraries. But when navigating to Site Contents it cannot get the serverrelativeurl. Is it know issue ?

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serverRelativeUrl')

Reference from https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-breadcrumb

Comment: [SiteBreadcrumb.tsx](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/react-application-breadcrumb/src/extensions/siteBreadcrumb/components/SiteBreadcrumb.tsx) is trying to access `this.props.context.pageContext.list.serverRelativeUrl` which might not be available on site contents page hence you are receiving this error.

Comment: Is there anyway to make sure the serverRelativeUrl also works for site contents ?

Comment: I think you don't need breadcrumb on the site contents page, right? So, you can change the code to set the variable either to blank value or site URL conditionally.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP I have navigation set to all pages but I was expecting also works on the site contents page, since it is a _layout and not navigating to pages. I feel i need to make sure it works on site contents.